# How exactly does firefox differ from ie in handling multiple (duplicate) posts?

Tags: ajax, http, firefox, post, internet-explorer-7

I ran into a bug in Firefox involving some out-of-sync information on my form when using the reload button after some form data had been modified (through AJAX).

In IE (7), refreshing always seems to re-submit the originally submitted data.  So, if I load a form which is then modified through JS/AJAX and refresh, I see what I saw on the first load.

In Firefox (4), I tend (at least in this case) to see the newer data.  However, because I neglected to update certain form elements, the form seems to get re-submitted with partially incorrect data, in this case potentially bringing about serious confusion.

My question is, what exactly is the difference between the way Firefox and IE handle re-posting?  Is it documented anywhere?  Is either way more standard?  And what about other browsers?

**Edit**:  It might be worth noting that Firefox also seems to re-render only certain elements (in my case a label's class changes, but not an input's disabled status).  Does Firefox have special rules for how it updates the DOM when refreshing and re-POSTing?

I checked the return from the (re)POST in FF, and confirmed that it has some unusual behavior.  In the source of the return I get this bit:

```
<label id="delSheetContainer"
      title="Estimate Sheets with Schedule Activities in the past may not be deleted."
      class="">
   <input id="delSheet" name="delSheet"
      type="checkbox"
      tabindex="3"
      value="false"
      //Inserted note: this is where the disabled value would have been
      onclick="this.value=(this.value && 1); bSave=true; setBtn(this.checked);"
   />Delete Sheet
</label>
```

But in the browser (and Firebug), I see a still-disabled checkbox.  The label, however, has been properly updated.  Can anybody detail this behavior as well? (references appreciated!)

**Edit**: As Boris explained, Firefox maintains "form state" across refreshes.  My problem is actually being caused by this fact; the server is returning the right stuff, but Firefox maintains the form state anyway.

Comment: Now I feel more confused than before... I'll have to do some more testing soon so I can understand this more clearly...  I'll update the question further when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure which effect you're seeing here based on the description, but when you do a reload (not a force-reload) Firefox will keep the values of modified form inputs at whatever value they were *before* the reload.

So if you have a page with this markup:

```
<input name="x">
```

and the user types in "foo" into the textbox and then reloads, the input after the reload will still contain the string "foo".

This applies to hidden inputs whose values are modified via JavaScript as well, which may well account for the behavior you observe.

There is no standard covering reload behavior, really.

Comment: @Boris Thanks, that makes sense.  Any thoughts about the rendering thing?

Comment: @Boris It seems that the un-updated elements aren't really causing the rendering difference (see edit).  Edit: actually, I'm not sure... hold on...

Comment: @Boris the problem I'm running into is that the form that first gets POSTed to get to the page is different than the form on the page, so updating the form element with getElementById isn't working.

Comment: @Boris OK, I'm going to have to look into this more at a later time; I'm getting really confused about how I'm actually handling these posts.. they (the first form and the problem form) get posted to the same destination, but very different forms are returned.

Comment: @dafrazzman What's persisted across reloads is "form state".  That includes modified values, modified disabled state for form controls, modified checked state for radios and checkboxes, and a few other things.  Everything else is reloaded from cache or network.  That explains the behavior you see with label classes vs input disabled values.

Comment: @Boris I think I'm getting it now.  This feels like pretty much unwanted behavior in this case; any thoughts for a smooth fix off-hand?  I guess an onLoad Script to refresh those things would work, but that seems kind of lame.

Comment: Hmm.  You can force no state restoration on a particular control by setting autocomplete="off" on it.  This also disables form autocomplete for that control, of course.  You can also disable it for a page in general by setting it to be cache-control:no-store, but that also disables various caching.

Comment: @Boris Cool, I will consider those options.